# C++ 11 std::enable_if overloading in Visual C++ 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

The following code snippet was taken from [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Traits.h), checking whether one integer  is greater than the other in compile time.

```
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename RHS, RHS rhs, typename LHS>
bool greater_than_impl(
  typename std::enable_if<
    (rhs <= std::numeric_limits<LHS>::max()
      && rhs >= std::numeric_limits<LHS>::min()),
    LHS
  >::type const lhs
) {
  return lhs > rhs;
}

template <typename RHS, RHS rhs, typename LHS>
bool greater_than_impl(
  typename std::enable_if<
    (rhs > std::numeric_limits<LHS>::max()),
    LHS
  >::type const
) {
  return false;
}

template <typename RHS, RHS rhs, typename LHS>
bool greater_than_impl(
  typename std::enable_if<
    (rhs < std::numeric_limits<LHS>::min()),
    LHS
  >::type const
) {
  return true;
}

template <typename RHS, RHS rhs, typename LHS>
bool greater_than(LHS const lhs) {
  return greater_than_impl<
    RHS, rhs, typename std::remove_reference<LHS>::type
  >(lhs);
}

int test()
{
    auto v = greater_than<int, 0, int>(0);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.8.2 show me the expected compiling result, but Visual C++ 2013 gives me an error at the second template function `greater_than_impl`:

> C2995: function template has already been defined

seems that std::enable_if overloading was not recognized, is Visual C++ 2013 lack of any SFINAE feature?

Comment: It would be very helpful to include additional information about the errors in your question. Which lines does the error appear on? What's the exact error text it gives you?

Comment: Only related bug report I could find: [Weird behavior of std::enable_if<T> produces C2995 in Visual C++.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811603/weird-behavior-of-std-enable-if-t-produces-c2995-in-visual-c)

Comment: This requires `constexpr` for `numeric_limits::max()` and `min()`, which VS2013 doesn't have. It *might* work if you install the latest CTP, I believe that adds some `constexpr` support but even then it's unlikely they've updated the stdlib. But I don't understand the need for this in any case; if you have `constexpr` support, why not just implement it like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4731c527f4877ba)? Also, C++14 adds `constexpr` to [`std::greater::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VC++ 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) doesn't support constexpr. And from what I can tell [they implement `max` and `min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s086ab1z.aspx) as non-const `static` functions. You can't use them where constant expressions are required, i.e.:

```
#include <limits>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, std::numeric_limits<int>::max()> a;
}

error C2975: '_Size' : invalid template argument for 'std::array', expected compile-time constant expression
```

As a workaround, I've tried to copy libstdc++'s implementation of `numeric_limits`, something like the following:

```
struct wrapper_base
{
  // member variables
};

template <typename T>
struct wrapper : public wrapper_base
{
    static const T max()
    {
        return T();
    }

    static const T min()
    {
        return T();
    }
};

template <>
    struct wrapper<int>
{
    static const int max()
    {
        return INT_MAX;
    }

    static const int min()
    {
        return INT_MIN;
    }
};
```

Unfortunately, this gives the same function template redefinition error. You can use `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` directly, but that would require specializing for 16 types (in libstdc++'s case.) It's better to probably avoid this approach altogether and follow [Praetorian's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003408/c-11-stdenable-if-overloading-in-visual-c-2013/22004002#comment33350760_22003408) advice.